# Understanding BackboneJS flow

Tags: backbone.js

I have been given a Project which is written entirely in Backbone.js, which I am supposed to change according to our specific needs. I have been studying Backbone.js for the past 2 weeks. I have changed the basic skeleton UI and a few of the features as needed. However I am trying to understand the flow of the code so that I can make further changes.

Specifically, I am trying to search some content on Youtube. I have a controller which uses a collection to specify the url and parse and return the response. The code is vast and I get lost where to look into after I get the response. I tried to look into views but it only has a div element set. Could someone help me to proceed. I wont be able to share the code here, but a general idea of where to look into might be useful.

## Code Snippet

```
define([
    'models/youtubeModelForSearch',
    'coretv/config',
    'libs/temp/pagedcollection',
    'coretv/coretv'
],function( youtubeModelForSearch, Config, PagedCollection, CoreTV ) {

    "use strict";

    return PagedCollection.extend({
        model: youtubeModelForSearch,

        initialize: function() {
            this.url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?v=2&alt=json&max-results=20';
        },

        fetch: function(options) {

            if (options === undefined) options = {};
            if (options.data === undefined) options.data = {};
            //options.data.cmdc      = Config.getCMDCHost();
            //CoreTV.applyAccessToken(options);
            PagedCollection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);  
        },

        parse: function(response) {

            var temp = response.feed
            /*temp["total"] = 20;
            temp["start"] = 0;
            temp["count"] = 10; */
            console.log(temp);
            return temp.entry;
        },

        inputChangeFetch: function(query) {
            this.resetAll();
            if(query) {
                this.options.data.q = query;
               // this.options.data.region = Config.api.region;
                //this.options.data.catalogueId = Config.api.catalogueId;
                this.setPosition(0);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your collection endpoint is correctly set and working. When you want to get the data from the server you can call `.fetch()` on you collection.

When you do this, it will trigger an `request` event. Your views or anybody else can listen to it to perform any action.

When the data arrives from the server, your `parse` function is called, it is set using `set` or `reset`, depending the options you passed along `fetch()`. This will trigger any event related to the `set`/`reset` (see the documentation). During `set`/`reset`, the data retrieved from your server will be parsed using `parse` (you can skip it, passing `{ parse: false }`.

Right after that, if you passed any success callback to your `fetch`, it will be called with `(collection, response, options)` as parameters.

And, finally, it will trigger a `sync` event.

If your server does not respond, it will trigger an `error` event instead of all this.

Hope, I've helped.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I see what you are saying, I just added some code snippet. I parsed it have the response as needed. The next thing I am stcuk with is iterating through the response. I see it is not done in view or template. If you refer to the snippet, could you tell me what is happening after the parse. Should I be looking into PagedCollection?

Comment: What do you mean by iterating through the response? After the fetch you can see the mdoels of you collection using `collectionInstace.models`.